# Apache solr views, Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views, search

I am using D7, views 3, apache solr views modules. I have created a view with 2 contextual filters for apache solr. I want to view the solr query built using my contextual filters. But the view preview is displaying the text "No query was run".

Is there any way to view the solr query at preview page?

Comment: Often means no results. What are you entering into the contextual filter field in the preview area and what are the contextual filters you have configured?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel), and enable page show devel page query.

**Devel:**

> A suite of modules containing fun for module developers and themers.
>
> - Helper functions for Drupal developers and inquisitive admins. This module can print a summary of all database queries for each page request at the bottom of each page. The summary includes how many times each query was executed on a page (shouldn't run same query multiple times), and how long each query took (short is good - use cache for complex queries).
> - Also a `dprint_r($array)` function is provided, which pretty prints arrays. Useful during development. Similarly, a `ddebug_backtrace()` is offerred. See full [demo](http://ratatosk.net/drupal/tutorials/debugging-drupal.html).
> - Accelerate development of your site or module by quickly generating nodes, comments, terms, users, and more.

Comment: What do you mean by "enable page show devel page query"?  Do you mean "Display query log" on admin/config/development/devel?